# Помогите решить задачку( Python)

Tags: python-3.6

Суть решения почти понятна, но не знаю как и куда вписать все значения вышек, чтоб потом сравнить их и найти рабочие, не так давно пайтон изучаю)
Ссылка на задачу ACMP:
https://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=596

Answer (score 4):

а в чем проблема то?

каждая станция характеризуется координатами `(x, y)` и и радиусом `r`

кроме того известны координаты абонента `(a, b)`

значит надо считать станции для которых выполняется условие

```
(x-a)**2 + (y-b)**2 <= r**2
```

значит алгоритм такой:

1. отфильтровать только те станции, которые удовлетворяют данным критериям
2. подсчитать сколько станций с одинаковыми названиями из отфильтрованного списка

Лично я бы сначала из input файла сформировал бы словарь где в качестве ключа был бы список опсосов, а в качестве значения - список характеристик станций (т.е. список кортежей или списков, не суть)

дальше идем по словарю и для каждого опсоса делаем фильтрацию по указанному выше критерию

в итоге у нас на выходе будет словарь опсос:кол-во станций, и уж потом его можно превратить в список и отсортировать, если это требуется